# How to conditionally prevent Outbound messages

Tags: twilio

My developer has been trying to block outbound messages from salesforce if certain criteria are not met from a related salesforce record without success yet. There must be a way to suppress this callout to the Twilio API in salesforce or set a rule to prevent the outbound from being delivered within Twilio.

Comment: why not add that filter in workflow?

Comment: Do you mean Setup > Workflow > Outbound Messages, or do you mean messages sent by Twilio through some other triggering mechanism?

Comment: The Message object from the Twilio managed package. There's no standard functionality that can prevents the actual sms message from being delivered to the recipient even though we immediately delete the creation of the Message record and any entity on the Twilio that is created during an outbound message from salesforce.